# Vaadin. Combo box responsive popup window

Tags: css, vaadin, responsive, vaadin7

I have several combo boxes all over the page. And there is one combo box that I want to be responsive.

Let's assume I have layout containing it, just like this:

```
public class MyLayout extends CssLayout ... {
    ...
    void initLayout {
        displayBoxFilter = new ComboBox();
        displayBoxFilter.addStyleName("displayBoxFilter");
    }
}
```

and I have CSS like this:

```
.MyUI {
  ...
  .displayBoxFilter {
    color: red;
  }
}

.MyUI[width-range~="0-767px"] {
  ...
  .displayBoxFilter {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

But when I do this, only combo-box-caption colors get changed. But I also want to change the color of the popup window.

According to combo box CSS style rules (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-combobox.html) i add `v-filterselect-suggestpopup` and nested styles outside `MyUI` style:

```
.v-filterselect-suggestpopup {
  .gwt-MenuItem {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
.v-filterselect-suggestpopup[width-range~="0-767px"] {
  .gwt-MenuItem {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

After that, i have a combo box with *caption* colors that responsively get changed. But popup window color remains same (always yellow).

I think it's because popup window is rendered outside my responsive UI. `Responsive.makeResponsive(displayBoxFilter)` didn't work. How do I make this window responsive?

Any suggestions would be helpful! 
Thanks in advance

**UPD** based on Jouni's answer (worked for me):
I have added `@media` outside `@mixin` in `mytheme.scss` like this:

```
@mixin mytheme {
  @include theme;
  ...
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .mytheme {
    .gwt-MenuItem {
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation in the Responsive extension, that it doesn’t apply to any overlay elements (except the Window component).

You’re best workaround is to use regular CSS media queries.